# Запуск программ по расписанию через waitable timer

Tags: c#

Этот вопрос я уже задавал но возникли неожиданные трудности
Вот мой код:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr lpTimerAttributes, bool bManualReset, string lpTimerName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetWaitableTimer(IntPtr hTimer, [In] ref long pDueTime, int lPeriod, IntPtr pfnCompletionRoutine, IntPtr lpArgToCompletionRoutine, bool fResume);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject(IntPtr handle, uint milliseconds);

static IntPtr handle;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string date, time, datenow = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), timenow = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), way;
    int ret = 0;

    //  MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    // MessageBox.Show(timenow);
    Process p = new Process();

    using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Master\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Cursovaya OS 1\Cursovaya OS 1\bin\Debug\datetime"))
    {
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
            // Читаем строку из файла во временную переменную.
            date = fs.ReadLine();

            //time = fs.ReadLine();
            way = fs.ReadLine();
            //  MessageBox.Show(way.ToString());

            if (date.Length == 0) {; }
            else
            {
                DateTime utc;
                utc = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                MessageBox.Show(utc.ToString());
                long duetime = utc.ToFileTime();
                handle = CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr.Zero, true, "WaitableTimer");
                SetWaitableTimer(handle, ref duetime, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true);
                uint INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
                ret = WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
                p.StartInfo.FileName = way;
                p.Start();
                //tsikl++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

формат файла:

```
06.03.2017 15:01
D:\Des1.txt
06.03.2017 15:06
D:\Des1.txt
08.03.2017 15:08
D:\Des1.txt
```

Теперь он запускает процесс независимо от значения таймера(то есть три раза). Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это в каком вузе такие интересные курсовые пишут?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686289(v=vs.85).aspx), вы должны задавать время либо в абсолютном формате (как сейчас) либо в относительном (при отрицательных значениях).

Сейчас у вас задано абсолютное время срабатывания таймера, например: `06.03.2017 15:01`, но *сегодня не шестое марта*.